# How to sign installation files of a Visual Studio .msi

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, authenticode, code-signing-certificate

I recently purchased an authenticode certificate from globalsign and am having problems signing my files for deployment. There are a couple of .exe files that are generated by a project and then put into a .msi. When I sign the .exe files with the signtool the certificate is valid and they run fine. The problem is that when I build the .msi (using the visual studio setup project) the .exe files lose their signatures. So I can sign the .msi after it is built, but the installed .exe files continue the whole "unknown publisher" business. How can I retain the signature on these files for installation on the client machine?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Visual Studio creates two folders at compile time: obj and bin. Turns out, at least in my case, the output will always be copied from the obj folder into the bin folder. I was signing the executables in the bin folder only to have them overwritten and then packaged into the msi. Signing the executables in the obj folder solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had seen people attempting to convey the same else where though your answer was very concise and easy to read. You saved hours of my life : )

Answer (score 20):

You can add the following PostBuildEvent to your VS Setup project (project properties):

Windows 8.0:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /a  $(BuiltOuputPath)
```

Windows 10:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe" sign /a  $(BuiltOuputPath)
```

[image: Project properties window]

See [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for signtool usage. You can use the /f flag to specify the signing certificate, /p to specify the cert's password, etc

Also, note that $(BuildOuputPath) is misspelled. [This is on purpose.](https://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=9063) Thanks microsoft...

Comment: In my case signtool.exe present in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool\signtool.exe"

Comment: This works to sign the installer output, but it doesn't work to sign the files that are going to be deployed (the main executable and maybe other files of the application)

Answer (score 4):

Other option (The one that I'm doing) is creating the .msi first and then sign it using a pfx (certificate).

(I'm using a Code Signing Certificate that I bought at globalsign.com)

Open CMD:
run -> **powershell**

Where the certificate is located run and save the thumbprint:

**PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath .\CompanyCertificate.pfx**

Will get something like this **ABCFEDRABF229B78BF9C40EC47007C1234567890**, you must replace your value in the following execution line.

Then find where the **singtool.exe** is located and go there (Win 10 in my case, the msi must be in the same path as well) and execute the following:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit> .\signtool.exe sign /f CompanyCertificate.pfx /d "App Description" /p pfxPasswordHere /v /sha1 ABCFEDRABF229B78BF9C40EC47007C1234567890 /t "http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode" MyApplicationSetup.msi
```

**Number of files successfully Signed: 1**

**Number of warnings: 0**

**Number of errors: 0**

Congrats you got it!

You will see this new tab under .msi properties:

[image]

And finally try to install it:

[image: Success!!]

Comment: For anyone missing **signtool.exe**, it is part of the [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/).