# Encrypt setup / MSI files InstallShield

Tags: c#, security, windows-installer, silent-installer

I am using InstallShield to create the setup for my application. However, I want to ask if there is a way to decrypt my dlls and folders that comes alongside the .exe file? I don't want anyone to access my dlls and setup folders.

Comment: Once a user installed your software the DLL's needs to be stored decrypted on the users local filesystem  anyway. Why bother encrypting them in the MSI?

Comment: to avoid anyone to change in it in a way or another , and I want to set password for folders that alongside in exe to avoid anyone to play/access files in it

Comment: Sign your MSI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652301/how-to-sign-installation-files-of-a-visual-studio-msi

Comment: And you can't deny access to files to a user who installed it and/or needs the files to execute your program. Security is bound to a user, not to a process.

Comment: see also the blogs on OldNewThing with these titles: [*It rather involved being on the other side of this airtight hatchway*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22It+rather+involved+being+on+the+other+side+of+this+airtight+hatchway%22+SITE%3Ablogs.msdn.microsoft.com)

Comment: Are these assemblies or Win32 files or COM files or what? [I just added this answer yesterday for how to embed assemblies in a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54267966/129130). To protect such an assembly, you might need obfuscation that I am not up to speed on.